# .htaccess RewriteRule giving 500 server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^equipment /equipment.php [L]
```

It will throw a 500 server error... but if I were to replace the `equipment.php` with, for example, our contact page `contactUs.php` it will redirect to the contact page with no problems.

I have other rewrite rules that work fine - but I can't figure out why this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I needed to do `RewriteRule ^equipment/$ /equipment.php [L]`

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Limit your Rule by adding **$**

```
RewriteRule ^equipment$ /equipment.php [L]
```

Comment: @mdance: I think that's a different problem all together

Comment: @donald123: It's very well possible that's not what he was trying to achieve. Also, shouldn't the L flag make sure that there is no problem with his original rule?

Comment: I have other rules that are formatted the exact same way. For example: `RewriteRule ^contactus /contactUs.php [L]` works just fine. Could it be a problem with my `equipment.php` page?

Comment: when possible ... take a look in the apache error log file and post the error to say more